# Regex for finding variable references in a C file using Python

Tags: python, regex

Given a variable name such as `myvariable`, what regex could be used to replace (refactor) references to it with another variable name `myreplacementvariable`

e.g.

```
addr = &myvariable;
```

should turn into

```
addr = &myreplacementvariable;
```

BUT

```
int myvariable2 = 0;
```

should be left alone (because it's a different variable name that happens to contain the name of `myvariable`)

I am looking for a line or two of Python, probably with Regex.

Note: I am aware parsing C is incredibly difficult and am not looking for anything that thinks about scope. I also forsee `char *mystr = "myvariable";` causing problems but I can work around that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what level of solution you find acceptable? You are aware that the regex solution can break easily, but do you have some sort of assumptions in mind?

Comment: Do you know it is going to be int? Why don't you just check for `=` before the variable and replace it? Like `=.*myvariable`.

Comment: I would like a solution that ignores scope and `char *mystr = "myvariable";` problems but nothing else

Comment: @ATOzTOA No, I don't know variable types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
value = "addr = &myvariable;"
findVar = "myvariable"
m = re.findall("[&]{0};".format(findVar), value)
print m
# prints: ['&myvariable;']
```

Note that I escaped the ampersand by putting it within the [].
You could also escape it with two backslashes:

```
m = re.findall("\\&{0};".format(findVar), value)
```

**Edit:**

Here's a re.sub version based on discussion in the comments:

```
value = "addr = &myvariable;\naddr = &myvariable;\nfuncCall( &myvariable )"
oldVarName = "myvariable"
newVarName = "mynewvariable"
m = re.sub("(\\&){0}(;?)".format(oldVarName), r"\1"+newVarName+r"\2", value)
print m
# this will print:
# addr = &mynewvariable;
# addr = &mynewvariable;
# funcCall( &mynewvariable )
```

This pattern will have the same result as:

```
value.replace("&"+oldVarName,"&"+newVarName)
```

I'm using the parentheses for matching the ampersand at the start and the possible semicolon at the end. Then I'm using the \1 and \2 to put these matches back in within the replacement string. Note that this result would be similar to using: value.replace("&"+oldVarName, "&"+newVarName)

**EDIT:**
This is probably closer to what you need.

It replaces every instance starting with an ampersand AND contains the whole old variable name and doesn't contain any of the characters afterwards that are within [A-Za-z0-9_].

```
value = "addr = &myvariable;\naddr = &myvariable;\nfuncCall( &myvariable )\nfuncCall2( &myvariable, &myvariablelongername )"
oldVarName = "myvariable"
newVarName = "mynewvariable"
m = re.sub("(\\&){0}(?![A-Za-z0-9_])".format(oldVarName), r"\1"+newVarName, value)
print m
# prints:
# addr = &mynewvariable;
# addr = &mynewvariable;
# funcCall( &mynewvariable )
# funcCall2( &mynewvariable, &myvariablelongername )
```

(That last part is any valid character for in a variable name in C, after the first character which is required to start with: [A-Za-z_]. This is also mentioned in the answer by 'nhahtdh')

Using what nhahtdh provided as an example this would be a shorter version of the last example:

```
re.sub("(\\&){0}(?!\b)".format(oldVarName), r"\1"+newVarName, value)
```

Since it was new to me when writing this answer and it got mixed up in the comments by myself in this answer I'm adding this as information: The *r* in front of the strings like r"\1" turn the string into a raw string.

> r 'a raw string where \ are kept (literalized): handy for regular expressions and windows paths!'
>   Source: http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#Strings

Comment: This looks really good, could `re.sub` be used to make the replace?

Comment: Also, I would like to not rely on the `;` being at the end of the variable reference (as I would like it to replace a variable reference in a function call)

Comment: You could try something like "[&]{0}[;]*".format(findVar) as a pattern. I'll quickly try if I can write an example to replace it within the input. ;)

Comment: If you would go with the version that takes matches with and without the semicolon at the end there isn't really a pattern because it's just replacing: &oldVar with &newVar. You could then better use: addr.replace("&myvariable","&mynewvariable")

Comment: Okay this looks very close. I tried `sourceref = re.sub(r"(\\&){0}(;?)".format(varname), r"\1"+str(newvarname)+r"\2", sourceref)` where varname and newvarname are variables. Unfortunately `sourceref` remained unchanged (i.e. nothing was replaced). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry. There was an error in the code. I edited my answer above since I was unable to edit my comment. All code in the answer should work as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:  `(\W)myvariable(\W)`  and replace with `\1myreplacementvariable\2`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\bvarname\b
```

`varname` can be any valid variable name (which is described by this regex `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*`).

Variable in C consists of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`, which is exactly what defined as word character `\w`, on which the word boundary `\b`'s definition is based on. We have to make sure the variable name is not part of other variable name, and is also not suffix to literal numbers (e.g. `3.0f`, `0x87654321UL`). That's why we use `\b` on both ends of the variable name.